# try and catch swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I don't under stand why I have to use `try` and `catch` with assignments like this one: 
[image: one]

Also if I put things in a `do ... while` block I would get this:

[image: two]

Comment: Can't answer the first block, but for the second one your function requires a return which you should provide for both the try and the catch

Comment: the thing is `habitsOfDay` is local to the `do` so I can't access it outside of `do`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just to use **do/catch** structure when you want to handle the error.
But if you're sure about your code won't give you any kind of error you can cancel the error propagation using 
try!

```
let habitsOfDay = try! Realm().objects(Habit).filter("durationByDays_days contains %@", daySelected)
```

You can find more about handling error in apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 2):

1. If you do not want to catch possible exceptions you should mark that function could throw them to the caller. You did it in the second sample (keyword `throws`) but not in the first one.
2. Function should return `Results<Habit>` but it does not. You have `return habitsOfDay` in the first sample but not in the second.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the guard statement.

```
guard let habitsOfDay = Realm().objects(Habit).filter("durationByDays_days contains %@", daySelected) else {return}
```